# .jsp page POST form with @Requestmapping through Spring does not work

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

When I try to call my form post in a jsp page using a submit button the page seems to be reloading, but nothing that happens in my @Requestmapping method gets called.

This is the Spring-annotated java method:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/TimeTracking.jsp", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String changeTheWeek(HttpServletRequest request) {

      if ("Previous Week".equals(request.getParameter("changeWeek"))) {
          this.subtractOneWeek();
      } if ("Next Week".equals(request.getParameter("changeWeek")))
      {
        this.addOneWeek();  
      }

        return "redirect:TimeTracking.jsp";
    }
```

Here is the jsp page's form:

```
<form name="ChangeWeek" method="POST" action="TimeTracking.jsp">
        <span> <input name="changeWeek" type="submit" value="Previous Week"/> Hours for the week of
            <%=currentWeek.firstDayOfThisWeek()%> until <%=currentWeek.lastDayOfThisWeek()%>
            <input name="changeWeek" type="submit" value="Next Week"/>
        </span>
</form>
```

Here's my spring-servlet.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Use @Component annotations for bean definitions -->
<context:component-scan base-package="controllers, daos, map, models, session, testControllers"  scoped-proxy="targetClass" />
<!-- added this because I think it makes annotations work? -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- Use @Controller annotations for MVC controller definitions -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"
    lazy-init="false" />

<!-- Add JPA support -->
<bean id="emf"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" lazy-init="false" >
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="SpaceTime" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter" />
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"
    lazy-init="false" />
<bean id="jpaAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
    lazy-init="true">
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
    <property name="showSql" value="false" />
</bean>
<!-- Ref: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/metadata.html#metadata-annotations-required -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
<bean id="myDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.44:3306/userexample" />
    <property name="username" value="nathan" />
    <property name="password" value="nathan" />
</bean>
<!-- Add Transaction support -->
<bean id="myTxManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" lazy-init="false" >
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />  
</bean>

<!-- Use @Transaction annotations for managing transactions -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTxManager"
    proxy-target-class="false" />
<!-- View resolver -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <!-- <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/> -->
</bean>
<!-- Use @Transaction annotations for managing transactions -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTxManager" />

</beans>
```

Here's the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
 <servlet>
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
<session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>jsp-pages/LogIn.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Here's the full java class (not just the method)

```
package controllers;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import models.CurrentWeek;
import models.User;

import org.joda.time.MutableDateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/**
 * this is the controller for current week, it lets you change the current week
 * and get values from the current week
 * 
     * @author CorayThan
 * 
 */
@Controller
public class CurrentWeekController {

@Autowired
private User user;

@Autowired
private CurrentWeek currentWeek;

/**
 * @return the user
 */
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

/**
 * @param user the user to set
 */
public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

/**
 * @return the currentWeek
 */
public CurrentWeek getCurrentWeek() {
    if (currentWeek==null) {
        this.createNewCurrentWeek();
    }
    return currentWeek;
}

/**
 * @param currentWeek the currentWeek to set
 */
public void setCurrentWeek(CurrentWeek currentWeek) {
    this.currentWeek = currentWeek;
}

/**
 * no arg constructor
 */
public CurrentWeekController() {

}

/**
 * this is a post method called when a button is clicked on the time tracking
 * jsp page. It reloads the page with a different week
 * @param pageWeek
 * @param request
 * @return
 */

  @RequestMapping(value = "/TimeTracking.jsp", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String changeTheWeek(HttpServletRequest request) {

      if ("Previous Week".equals(request.getParameter("changeWeek"))) {
          this.subtractOneWeek();
      } if ("Next Week".equals(request.getParameter("changeWeek")))
      {
        this.addOneWeek();  
      }

        return "redirect:TimeTracking.jsp";
    }

/**
 * this is the default method to show the time tracking page
 * @return
 */
//  @RequestMapping(value = "/TimeTracking.jsp")
//    public ModelAndView showTimeTracking() {
//        
//        return new ModelAndView("/TimeTracking.jsp", "command", this.getCurrentWeek());
//    }

/**
 * This creates a current week object by accepting a calendar. If that
 * calendar is set to Saturday, it will set all the days in that current
 * week object as calendars otherwise it will set all the days in that week
 * starting with the current day and counting back to Monday (the first day
 * of the week)
 * 
 * @param calendar
 * @return
 */
public CurrentWeek createCurrentWeek(MutableDateTime theCurrentDate) {

    int day = checkForNull(theCurrentDate);

    switch (day) {

    case 7:
        MutableDateTime sunday = (MutableDateTime) theCurrentDate.clone();
        this.getCurrentWeek().setSunday(sunday);
        theCurrentDate.addDays(-1);
        day--;
    case 6:
        MutableDateTime saturday = (MutableDateTime) theCurrentDate.clone();
        this.getCurrentWeek().setSaturday(saturday);
        theCurrentDate.addDays(-1);
        day--;
    case 5:
        MutableDateTime friday = (MutableDateTime) theCurrentDate.clone();
        this.getCurrentWeek().setFriday(friday);
        theCurrentDate.addDays(-1);
        day--;
    case 4:
        MutableDateTime thursday = (MutableDateTime) theCurrentDate.clone();
        this.getCurrentWeek().setThursday(thursday);
        theCurrentDate.addDays(-1);
        day--;
    case 3:
        MutableDateTime wednesday = (MutableDateTime) theCurrentDate
                .clone();
        this.getCurrentWeek().setWednesday(wednesday);
        theCurrentDate.addDays(-1);
        day--;
    case 2:
        MutableDateTime tuesday = (MutableDateTime) theCurrentDate.clone();
        this.getCurrentWeek().setTuesday(tuesday);
        theCurrentDate.addDays(-1);
        day--;
    case 1:
        MutableDateTime monday = (MutableDateTime) theCurrentDate.clone();
        this.getCurrentWeek().setMonday(monday);
        break;
    default:
        this.setCurrentWeek(null);
        break;

    }
    return this.getCurrentWeek();

}

/**
 * @param theCurrentDate
 * @return
 */
private int checkForNull(MutableDateTime theCurrentDate) {
    int day = 0;
    if (theCurrentDate != null) {
        day = theCurrentDate.getDayOfWeek();
    }
    return day;
}

/**
 * makes a new current week
 * 
 * @return
 */

public CurrentWeek createNewCurrentWeek() {
    MutableDateTime dateTime = MutableDateTime.now();
    CurrentWeek currentWeek = new CurrentWeek();
    this.setCurrentWeek(currentWeek);

    return createCurrentWeek(dateTime);
}

/**
 * subtracts one week from a currentweek
 * 
 * 
 * @return
 */
public void subtractOneWeek() {

    MutableDateTime newMonday = (MutableDateTime) this.getCurrentWeek().getMonday().clone();
    newMonday.addDays(-7);

    this.setCurrentWeek(createCurrentWeek(newMonday));


}

/**
 * adds one week to a currentweek
 * 
 * @param currentWeek
 * @return
 */
public void addOneWeek() {

    MutableDateTime newMonday = (MutableDateTime) this.getCurrentWeek().getMonday().clone();
    newMonday.addDays(7);

    this.setCurrentWeek(createCurrentWeek(newMonday));
}

/**
 * TODO: make this method into a method that accepts a current week and
 * checks if you can add a week to it without going entirely into the future
 * 
 * @param currentWeek
 * @return
 */
public CurrentWeek checkIfCurrentWeekIsEntirelyInFuture() {
    return this.getCurrentWeek();

}

/**
 * returns the first day of the week as a date time
 * 
 * @return
 */

public String firstDayOfThisWeek() {

    MutableDateTime firstDay = (MutableDateTime) this.getCurrentWeek().getMonday().clone();
    firstDay.addDays(-1);

    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");

    return dateFormatter.print(firstDay);
}

/**
 * returns the last day of this week as a date time
 * 
 * @return
 */

public String lastDayOfThisWeek() {


    MutableDateTime firstDay = (MutableDateTime) this.getCurrentWeek().getMonday().clone();
    firstDay.addDays(5);

    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");

    return dateFormatter.print(firstDay);
}

}
```

And finally, here is the full TimeTracking.jsp page that the form is in:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<jsp:useBean id="timeTracking"
class="controllers.TimeTrackingController" scope="request" />
<jsp:useBean id="currentWeek" class="controllers.CurrentWeekController"
scope="request" />
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Time Tracking Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "../javascriptpages/timeTracking.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div>
    <h1>User Time Tracking Page</h1>
</div>
<div id="content">

<form name="ChangeWeek" method="POST" action="TimeTracking.jsp">
        <span> <input name="changeWeek" type="submit" value="Previous Week"/> Hours for the week of
            <%=currentWeek.firstDayOfThisWeek()%> until     <%=currentWeek.lastDayOfThisWeek()%>
            <input name="changeWeek" type="submit" value="Next Week"/>
        </span>
</form>


        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Sunday</th>
                <th>Monday</th>
                <th>Tuesday</th>
                <th>Wednesday</th>
                <th>Thursday</th>
                <th>Friday</th>
                <th>Saturday</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td><%=timeTracking.totalWorkTimeForOneDate(currentWeek.getCurrentWeek().getSunday())%>    </td>
                <td><%=timeTracking.totalWorkTimeForOneDate(currentWeek.getCurrentWeek().getMonday())%></td>
                <td><%=timeTracking.totalWorkTimeForOneDate(currentWeek.getCurrentWeek().getTuesday())%></td>
                <td><%=timeTracking.totalWorkTimeForOneDate(currentWeek.getCurrentWeek().getWednesday())%></td>
                <td><%=timeTracking.totalWorkTimeForOneDate(currentWeek.getCurrentWeek().getThursday())%></td>
                <td><%=timeTracking.totalWorkTimeForOneDate(currentWeek.getCurrentWeek().getFriday())%></td>
                <td><%=timeTracking.totalWorkTimeForOneDate(currentWeek.getCurrentWeek().getSaturday())%></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <input type="button" value="<%=timeTracking.displayClockButton()%>"
            onClick="clockInOrOutReloadPage()">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your web.xml you have mapping for *.html extension, while trying to access page which is mapped as .jsp.

You need to change your mapping to

> @RequestMapping(value = "TimeTracking")

and fix the action of the html form to `action ="TimeTracking.html"`

Also, if you are new to Spring MVC and want to use its features, please check Spring MVC Showcase demo http://blog.springsource.org/2010/07/22/spring-mvc-3-showcase/

Comment: So I made those changes, but it still doesn't work. When I click the submit button it gives me a 404 error "RequestURI=/SpaceTime/jsp-pages/TimeTracking.html" But even if I change the request mapped method to not return the time tracking page at all it still says it can't resolve the time tracking page!

Comment: Does it enter to your controller method?(you can set a breakpoint in debug mode)

Comment: I tried that, and it doesn't seem to be entering my controller method at all. So it must be my jsp form that is improperly written?

Comment: The simplest thing to do is to replace your posr method with get and try to open the page from the browser to see that it's mapped correctly - also you can configure your logger for org.springframework namespace to DEBUG level, the most hardocore method is to set a breakpoint in the spring DispatcherServlet class

Comment: It seems that the address in you form should be prefixed with ..\ in other words  you shouldn't access your spring controlled pages via jsp-pages sub path at all!

Comment: I tried to change it to GET, but now when I build the project with maven it gives the error: "Aug 07, 2012 11:40:31 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpaceTime/jsp-pages/TimeTracking.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'"

Comment: see previous comment it's /SpaceTime/TimeTracking.html

Comment: after your get method works in browser change it back to post, correct the jsp form if needed, check again that your method is executed, if the method is executed but after returning the view's name gives 404 error, then check your view name and ViewResolver configuration

Comment: I think I might actually be getting somewhere now! Now I'm getting a different error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope 'Session'" which I think has something to do with a bean I scoped as Session

Comment: thank you so much Boris! I think I can take it from here. It seems to have been the attempt to access the spring controlled page via jsp-pages.

Comment: try session instead of Session, but I'm actually on a smartphone can't help)))

Answer (score 0):

your url pattern is *.html. So change your action to *TimeTracking.html*. And change your request mapping to */TimeTracking.html*

Answer (score 0):

Either change the web.xml url-pattern of spring servlet to * or change the action name to TimeTracking.html and also requestmapping's value attribute to /TimeTracking.html. From the jsp page what I understand is we are using input type as button instead of submit and there is an event on the button also, try to change the input type to submit with the action name and requestmapping' value attribute changed to TimeTracking.html.